# Is this the correct way to disable a user in Asp.net Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement a way to lock a user out but keep all their data in the system. I have been reading the documentation for `SetLockoutEnabledAsync` and it seems to be the thing I'm looking for.

I implemented the below code in my Controller, but I'm not sure if it's correct or if I'm having a problem with the view. So my question is in two parts: Is this code correct, and if so, what should the View look like?

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Disable (ApplicationUser Id)
{
    if(Id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var en = await _usermanager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(Id, true);
    if( en == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return View(en);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Disable")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DisableConfirmed(ApplicationUser Id)
{
    var en = await _usermanager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(Id, true);
    await _usermanager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(Id, true);
    await _application.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("ListUsers", "Admin");
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You didn't really explain it. It looks to me like that code *enables* lock out, it does not actually lock anything. And, what your view should look like is not something anyone can answer.

Comment: i might have misunderstood the documentation, but Setlocoutenabledasync locks out the account when it's set to true, or is that wrong?

Comment: and what i'm trying to do is to have a button that disables a user but keeps their information in the system

Comment: [This might be dated](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Lockout/) but give it a look.